# Optional parameter vector

Tags: c++

How to make optional vector parameter? I read in some thread to use pointer to vector but I get following error:

```
 redefinition of default argument: parameter 1
```

with code error C2572.

```
void EnumerateProcessInformations(std::vector<DWORD> &o_processId, const std::vector<std::wstring> *o_processName = nullptr)
{
    HANDLE hSnapProcess = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    PROCESSENTRY32W process;
    process.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32W);
    Process32FirstW(hSnapProcess, &process);
    do
    {
        if (process.th32ProcessID != 0)
        {
            o_processId.emplace_back(process.th32ProcessID);
            if (*o_processName != nullptr) { *o_processName.emplace_back(process.szExeFile); }
        }
    } while (Process32NextW(hSnapProcess, &process));
    CloseHandle(hSnapProcess);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<DWORD> processId;
    EnumerateProcessInformations(processId, nullptr);
    for (auto& p : processId)
    {
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the *exact* error message you get. *"redifinition"* is not a word. If you are running Visual Studio on a non-English system, [install the English language pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio#step-6---install-language-packs-optional) to get English error messages.

Comment: @IInspectable the error nessage **redefinition of default argument: parameter 1** with code error C2572. as i checked to solve it default paremeter should undefined. how make default paremeter undefined?

Comment: @stephenju post complete code somewhere. Do you have EnumerateProcessInformations() already declared?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your use of a pointer:

- you are dereferencing the pointer before checking it for `nullptr`. You are not checking if the pointer is null, you are checking if the vector being pointer to is null.
- you are declaring it as pointing to a `const vector`, which means you can't call any mutating methods on the vector, like `emplace_back`.

Try this instead:

```
void EnumerateProcessInformations(..., std::vector<std::wstring> *o_processName = nullptr);

...

void EnumerateProcessInformations(..., std::vector<std::wstring> *o_processName)
{
    ...
    if (o_processName) o_processName->emplace_back(process.szExeFile);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also, the error quoted in the question is the result of applying [default arguments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) in the function definition. Default arguments can only be used in function declarations.

Comment: some result redifinition of default argument 1

Comment: @IInspectable yes, but in the case of a standalone function that is implemented solely in the same cpp file it is used in, its declaration and definition may be one and the same thing. And the way the OP's code is presented, that may be the case in this situation.

Comment: The fact that the OP presented a compiler error is enough information to infer, that the code the OP posted is incomplete, and there *is* a declaration preceding the definition.